# Write a function that returns a new string containing all matches. Each match is then replaced by replacement characters

Tags: javascript

Write a function that returns a new string containing all matches. Each match is then replaced by replacement characters.I cannot used built-in function ex:replace,split,splice...
Hi guys can you help me with this.I am new to this and i am sorry that the code didn't make sense.Thanks

```
function func4(str,chartoChange,chartoReplace){
  var result = "";
  for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    var x = str.charAt(i);
    if (x==chartoChange){
        // How to replace with chartoReplace
    }
    result += str
   }
   return result
   }
```

Example (("abc","a","X") return Xbc

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate either the `chartoReplace` or the original `str[i]` with `result`, depending on whether `str[i] === chartoChange`:

```js
function func4(str, chartoChange, chartoReplace) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += str[i] === chartoChange
    ? chartoReplace
    : str[i];
  }
  return result
}
console.log(func4("abc", "a", "X")) // return Xbc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex and `replace`:

```js
function func4(str, charToChange, charToReplace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(charToChange, "g"), charToReplace);
}

console.log(func4("abc", "a", "X"));
console.log(func4("Hello World", "l", "q"));
```